# AJAX send post request only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with ajax, as it sends only once my request, i have a cssmap plugin, and that plugin have the option onSecondClick which gives me the ability to do something when i click on it twice, my post request sends some data, to the sessions.php, in session.php i delete session, and then i put one again.

The js lines :

```
'onSecondClick' : function(e){

        var regionName = e.children("A").eq(0).text(),
        regionHref = e.children("A").eq(0).attr("href"),
        regionClass = e.attr("class").split(" ")[0];

        if(regionClass == "eu13" || regionClass == "eu16" || regionClass == "eu47"){
            //open model success

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'session',
                data: { country : regionClass },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $( "#success" ).click();
                }
            });

            //$( "#success" ).click();
        }else{
            //open model error
            $( "#error" ).click();
        }
    },
```

PS - the url is right, thats the url of the file, and the session is set, but only once and doesn't upadate.

session.php:

```
if(Input::get('country')){

    $countries = array(
        'eu13' => 'france',
        'eu16' => 'germany',
        'eu47' => 'united kingdom',
        //end of playable countries, the rest is bots!
        'eu5' => 'belgium',
        'eu27' => 'luxembourg',
        'eu33' => 'netherlands',
        'eu44' => 'switzerland',
        'eu20' => 'ireland'
    );
    if(Session::get('selected');){
        Session::delete('selected');
    }
    Session::put('selected',$countries[Input::get('country')]);

}
```

On the success, i click a button, which open a "model" from Bootstrap.

everything is ok, but the session always return the previous clicked country, and no matter how much i click other country, it doesn't change.

i've got no idea what the problem is, tried e.preventdefault(), cache: false, and some more options, nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Fistly check that your handler `onSecondClick` is called. BTW sounds like a click handler, so how do you bind it? Are you replacing in some way this element?

Comment: The code you posted does not use the country information you query. Specifically, the `data` argument to your `success`handler in the ajax call remains unused.

Comment: Wolff - i'm kinda new to js and ajax, so i have no idea what your talking about, the country is clicked ( the model open every single time i click it) the value of the session is not set.

Comment: collaspar - Input::get('country') IS $_POST['country'], thats the way i use it.

Comment: Are you sure that session.php is generating a new session like it should? If it is, and it's the displayed information in the modal that never changes, I might know the reason.

Comment: yes i'm sure, session is working fine as i use it in other places like login

Answer (score 0):

*It's hard to tell where the problem lies from your description, but if it's about presentation (i.e. you can verify that session.php does it's job, but still the modal presents the wrong info), this is probably the reason.*

Bootstrap modals are only, by default, filled with content once. After that it will use .toggle to show or hide.

If you want to update the information, you'll have to clear it first:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

This will clear any content from modals with class `modal` when it hides/closes. You can also use an id selector of course, like `#myModal`.

edit:

Try this ajax. What does the alert return?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "session",
    data: { "country": regionClass },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("#success").click();
    }
});
```

And add something like this to the end of your session.php:

```
echo $countries[Input::get('country')];
```

(php is not really my thing. I think that's correct though)

Comment: its not working, the value doesn't change, and after i refresh, the last value clicked before the refreshed is shown, so i can't refresh the page as well, any other way i can pass the value to php ?

Comment: @user3052629 Try with my new additions to see if you can get the php file to return data to ajax.

Comment: the alert return the name of the clicked city, i included the php page in the model, and the model just opens and closes after 1 sec.

Comment: so it seems like the ajax works, as it returns the right name (not just the class name, but the name from the array in session.php) but when i try to include session or use it, i get an error that country input is not exists.

Comment: @user3052629 Then yes, this has eliminated any other issue. the problem is with the setting/getting of sessions. I know i classic asp it's not ok to treat sessions like this. It needs a request between the actual "clearing" and "re-setting". Perhaps it would be better to just overwrite the existing sessions values? (skip the delete)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75411/discussion-between-user3052629-and-mackan).